# a method/algorithm to solve a nonlinear Diophantine equation like this

Tags: algorithms, diophantine-equations

I have a Diophantine equation like this

```
10xy + 7y + 9x = 123456789..... (a 270 digit number!!)
```

I have tried an online calculator to solve it 
https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM, 
but it is factoring that huge number, so it is taking a very very long time.

My question is :
Is there any algorithm to solve Diophantine equations on **this specific form**

```
10xy + 7y + 9x = c
```

where c is a **huge** ~300 digits number, **without the need for factorization**?

I need a solution that doesn't take forever to calculate,

the only constraint is that x and y are integers

thanks.

Comment: why do you want this at all? What is the source of the problem?

Comment: $(10x+7)(10y+9) = 10c + 63.$ This is still an enormous number, but might be easy to factor.

Comment: @Will Jagy
but I still need to know the factors of 10c+63 , right? that factorization is going to take a long time

Comment: You do need to understand that any $(x,y)$ solution gives a factoring of $10c+63$ into two numbers. The collection of ALL $(x,y)$ solution gives a complete factorization.

Comment: yes I understand you,
but it is the same problem

Comment: Did you do a primality test on $10c+63$, where $\,c = 123456789\ldots$?  What can you conclude if it is prime?

Comment: @Bill Dubuque
nope, I didn't, it is too large and it takes too long

Comment: @Omar No, it's small for primality tests.

Comment: I used an online tool https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM ,

 is there any better tool/algorithm/code you recommend?

Comment: What does Wolfram Alpha return for IsPrime[10c+63] (It should take < $1$ second)

Comment: If $\,7\mid c\,$ then $\,7\mid 10c+63\,$ so you'll get a factorization with $10x+7 = 7$. So that and the factorization from $\,10y+9 = -1\,$ will give at least 2 distinct solutions.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque
you are correct, the primality test is so fast.


what I did on the other website was factoring that number, so it took  a long time